# Lua: converting from float to int

Tags: lua, floating-point

Even though Lua does not differentiate between floating point numbers and integers, there are some cases when you want to use integers. What is the best way to covert a number to an integer if you cannot do a C-like cast or without something like Python's `int`?

For example when calculating an index for an array in

> idx = position / width

how can you ensure `idx` is a valid array index? I have come up with a solution that uses `string.find`, but maybe there is a method that uses arithmetic that would obviously be much faster. My solution:

```
function toint(n)
    local s = tostring(n)
    local i, j = s:find('%.')
    if i then
        return tonumber(s:sub(1, i-1))
    else
        return n
    end
end
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could use `math.floor(x)`

From the [Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.6):

> Returns the largest integer smaller than or equal to x.

Comment: You could extend this answer to deal with negative numbers by throwing in some bars: `math.floor(math.abs(x))`

Comment: Sure - but you need to put the sign back in afterwards otherwise your conversion to int is also an abs()

Answer (score 24):

Lua `5.3` introduced a new operator, called `floor division` and denoted by `//`

Example below:

> Lua 5.3.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
>
> >12//5
>
> 2

More info can be found in the [lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html)

Comment: ...which you can use with a divisor of `1` to round both negative and positive numbers to the nearest integer (the rounding mode appears to be towards -inf).

Answer (score 14):

@Hofstad is correct with the `math.floor(Number x)` suggestion to eliminate the bits right of the decimal, you might want to round instead. There is no `math.round`, but it is as simple as `math.floor(x + 0.5)`. The reason you want to round is because floats are usually approximate. For example, `1` could be `0.999999996`

> 12.4 + 0.5 = 12.9, floored 12
>
> 12.5 + 0.5 = 13, floored 13
>
> 12.6 + 0.5 = 13.1, floored 13

```
local round = function(a, prec)
    return math.floor(a + 0.5*prec) -- where prec is 10^n, starting at 0
end
```

Answer (score 3):

why not just use `math.floor()`? it would make the indices valid so long as the numerator and denominator are non-negative and in valid ranges.