# Lua: What is typical approach for using calculated values in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, lua, floating-point

What is the typical approach in LUA (before the [introduction of integers in 5.3](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html#changes)) for dealing with calculated range values in for loops? Mathematical calculations on the start and end values in a *numerical for* loop put the code at risk of bugs, possibly nasty latent ones as this will only occur on certain values and/or with changes to calculation ordering. Here's a concocted example of a loop not producing the desire output:

```
a={"a","b","c","d","e"}
maybethree = 3 
maybethree = maybethree / 94
maybethree = maybethree * 94
for i = 1,maybethree do print(a[i]) end
```

This produces the unforuntate output of two items rather than the desired three (tested on 5.1.4 on 64bit x86):

```
a
b
```

Programmers unfamiliar with this territory might be further confused by **print()** output as that prints 3!

The application of a rounding function to the nearest whole number could work here. I understand the [approximatation with FP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and why this fails, I'm interested in what the typical style/solution is for this in LUA.

Related questions:

- [Lua for loop does not do all iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654496/lua-converting-from-float-to-int)
- [Lua: converting from float to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154301/lua-for-loop-does-not-do-all-iterations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to avoid this reliance on floating-point math where floating-point precision may become an issue. Or, more realistically, just be aware of when you are using FP and be mindul of the precision issue. This isn’t a Lua problem that requires a Lua-specific solution.

`maybethree` is a misnomer: it is *never* three. Your code above is deterministic. It will always print just `a` and `b`. Since the `maybethree` variable is less than three, of course the `for` loop would not execute 3 times.

The `print` function is also behaving as defined/expected. Use `string.format` to show thr FP number in all its glory:

```
print(string.format("%1.16f", maybethree)) -- 2.9999999999999996
```

Still need to use calculated values to control your `for` loop? Then you already mentioned the answer: implement a rounding function.

Comment: I think lua puts the naive programmer at higher risk than other languages? For example, if you try a similar thing in Python 3 with for i in range(maybethree) then it will throw a TypeError exception.

Comment: Perhaps. Thats said, it is difficult to program under the weight of too much naivete. Have to keep learning! That’s what’s great about SO.

Comment: Does the language specification require 64 bit IEEE 754 and does it specify a rouding method, e.g. FE_TONEAREST. It feels like that would have an influence on the likelyhood of maybethree being 3.